# How to use custom Cordova plugin methods in Angular/Ionic service

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, angular-services

I'm working on integrating a custom Cordova plugin into an Ionic app. We had a 3rd party create a Cordova plugin to interface with a bluetooth device. Running `cordova platform ls` shows the plugin has been correctly installed:

```
$ cordova plugin ls
> com.sitename.product 0.0.0 "DeviceProbe"
```

The plugin contains a `probe.js` file containing methods for connecting, reading, polling and other actions.

**/plugins/com.sitename.product/www/probe.js**

```
var callNative = function(service, action, success, error, args) {
    if(args === undefined) args = [];
    cordova.exec(success, error, service, action, args);
};

var thermProbe = {

    // Methods here

};

module.exports = thermProbe;
```

In order to use the plugin in our controllers I need to create an Angular service wrapper, as [described here](http://trinhtrunganh.com/correct-way-to-integrate-cordova-plugin-in-angularjs-ionic-framework/).

I've created a factory to handle this.

**/lib/probe/probe.js**

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    var serviceId = 'Probe';
    angular.module('thermProbe').factory(serviceId, ['$q', Probe]);

    function Probe($q) {

        var service = {
            'connect': connect,
            'disconnect': disconnect,
            'getReading': getReading,
            'getName': getName, 
            'getHigh': getHigh,
            'getLow': getLow,
            'pollReading': pollReading,
            'stopPolling': stopPolling,
            'isPolling': isPolling
        };

        return service;

        // Method wrappers

        function connect() {

            var q = $q.defer(); 

            if($window.cordova){
              cordova.plugins.thermProbe.connect(function (result) {
                q.resolve(result);
              }, function (err) {
                q.reject(err);
              });
            }
            return q.promise;

        }

    }

})();
```

Injecting the `Probe` service into a controller works fine. When I run this on my device (using `ionic run android`) I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
```

tracing back to the line containing `cordova.plugins.thermProbe.connect()`.

I've also tried using `cordova.plugins.probe.connect()` but receive the same error.

How can I get the methods from `/plugins/com.sitename.product/www/probe.js` to work in `/lib/probe/probe.js`?

Comment: you could try to deploy your application and inspect it in the sources tab there should be a cordova.plugin.js there you can see which plugins are beeing loaded and how they can be used, if cordova is not defined just use if($window.cordova){do your magic here} in the ionicready function

Comment: Do you think cordova is undefined because I'm viewing it in the browser @stackg91?

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error (and `console.log`ing) I was able to solve this.

The `$window` object has a `probe` object containing all the needed methods. I'm guessing the `probe` name comes from the Cordova plugin config.

**plugin.xml**

```
<js-module src="www/probe.js" name="probe">
  <clobbers target="probe" />
</js-module>
<platform name="ios">
  <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
    <feature name="probe">
      <param name="ios-package" value="productName"/>
    </feature>
  </config-file>
  ...
  ...
</platform>
<platform name="android">
  <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
    <feature name="probe">
      <param name="android-package" value="com.sitename.productName"/>
      <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
  </config-file>
  ...
  ...
</platform>
```

To use the methods:

```
function connect() {

  var q = $q.defer(); 

  if($window.probe){
    $window.probe.connect(function (result) {
      q.resolve(result);
    }, function (err) {
      q.reject(err);
    });
  }

  return q.promise;

}
```